# how to do autosave form data into single array in angular 4

Tags: angular

How to implement Autosave form data in angular 6.Iam getting saved content in new elements in array whenever i call setinterval to autosave for every 30 seconds, I want saved content into single element in a array.

Comment: show some code, what you have tried

Comment: i have tried using this setInterval(() => this.savedraft(), 1000*10)  .In savedraft function iam calling  form.value() and storing it in the array

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways, e.g:

1. **Using reactive forms:**

```
this.yourForm.valueChanges().subscribe(formData => { //do something});
```

this approach is automatic and doesn't have delay

2. **Using template-driven forms (ngModel) and rxjs timer:**

```
timer(2500).subscribe( () => { //do saving});
```

this approach will do your logic every 2.5 seconds.